# Survey JS - How to nest model data

Tags: reactjs, surveyjs

I have a nested model like this:

```
"pages": [
    {
        "name": "nest1",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "panel",
                "name": "nest2",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "panel",
                        "name": "nest3",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "text",
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "lastname",
                                "type": "text",
                            },
                        ]
                        
                    }
                ]
             },
        ]
    }  
]
```

when the survey is done I got this answer

```
{
    "name": value1,
    "lastname": value2
}
```

but what I expect is something like this

```
  "nest1": {
    "nest2": {
      "nest3": {
        "name": "value1",
        "lastname": "value2"
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I achieve this from the model or do I have to parse de data with some js?

Answer (score 0):

SurveyJS considers panels as a layout. You can change your question location in your panels and it will not change the survey response structure.
You are probably looking for [composite question types](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/customize-question-types/create-composite-question-types), that have the structure you need.

Thank you,
Andrew